# Is there a way to specify an extra class for a post or page with no title?

Tags: posts, css, pages, title

If I do a post or a page with no title, I'm left with an empty `h1` tag at the top of the post/page.

I'd like to either get rid of the `h1` in these cases, or else be able to add an extra CSS class to the post/page so that I can specify how to display the post (and the `h1`) differently when the post/page is published with no title.

Are either of these things possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add an extra class when there is no title

```
<h1<?php if(!get_the_title()){echo ' class="no-title"';}?>><?php the_title();?></h1>
```

Or to only display h1 tags when there is a title

```
<?php if(get_the_title()) { ?>
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
<?php }?>
```